# Jackson serializes generic but not deserialize

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

How can i make this work ? I look at the other questions but i cant figure it out how. Actually i dont know much about jackson. Maybe the "lombok" is cause the problem.  thank you in advance.

```
    @Data class A{String b;}
    @Data class B<T>{ T c; }


    A a1 = new A();
    a1.setB("sa");
    B<A> s = new B<A>();
    s.c = a1;

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String sj = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(s);
    System.out.println(sj); // {"c":{"b":"sa"}} 

    B<A> ba = objectMapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<B<A>>() {
    })
            .readValue(sj); // this is not working
```

Gives this error:

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot deserialize 
    EmbeddedTest$1B (of type local/anonymous) as a Bean.
```

Comment: Which Lombok annotation you have used. I have also used Jackson for deserializing having lombok @Data annotation.

Comment: @Data will generate methods so nothing serialization related.

Comment: Just @Data i have used.